# Header checkbox Selection by checking all checkboxes

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a radgrid in which the header has a checkbox and in the itemtemplate checkboxs. I want the header checkbox to be checked when all the checkboxs in the itemtemplate are checked.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/selectrowwithcheckbox/defaultcs.aspx